# Vue router access meta data from router-link

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I use `vue3` and `vue-router-4`, and am trying to hide some router links for unauthorized users:

Route file:

```
{
  path: "/users/create",
  name: "UserCreate",
  meta: {
    title: "Create user",
    requiresAuth: true
  },
  component: () =>
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "create" */ "@/views/Users/Create.vue")
}
```

As you can see I have `requiresAuth: true` meta in this route, so I want to hide this for guests.

I want to use something like this in my views (`v-if` part, which is not working):

```
<router-link v-if="route.meta.requiresAuth === isLoggedIn()" to="/users/create" class="nav-link"
      >Create user</router-link>
```

Please advise how I can achieve this, and if it's not possible with `meta fields` - what is the preferred way to hide links.

P.S. Of course all validation and checks of accesses will be performed at the back-end side, but I still don't want to show user links which they can't view.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this only hides the links, users can still access these routes through the URL. you need to use the `before` navigation guard in addition to hiding links:

Navigation guard :

```js
//router.js

router.beforeEach((to,from,next)=>{
   if ( to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) {
     if( isLoggedIn()) {
        next()
     }  else {
       // if user is not logged what should happen
    }
   } else {
     next()
   }
})
```

Hide links if they require Auth and the user is not authenticated:

```html
<router-link v-if="isLoggedIn()" to="/users/create" class="nav-link"> 
  Create user
</router-link>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$route` inside `v-if` points to the router-link's route? As far as I can see it always points to the current route, where user sits at the moment. When I need it to represent route where user will go, if he clicks this router-link. P.S. Thanks, I already use beforeEach, just need to hide link now.

Comment: @walemy I miss understood what you wanted to achieve, If you want to show the route link only for auth users then simply use that as a condition ( i updated ), meta values are to be used on the navigation guard

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani `isLoggedIn` should be a computed property and used without `()` `v-if="isLoggedIn"`

Comment: @Abdelillah Yes, i understand that this is an option, but it will lead to duplicatation of this "permissions" in routes file (for navigation guards) and then in router-link. So if in some point i decide to change this - i'll have to change this twice. And if I forget to change in one of two places - unexpected things will happen. While I want to have only one declaraion, and use it in both routes file and views (if it's possible).

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani And yes, I'm using this as computed property. Just simplified it here for the example. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @walemy pleasure to help, it would be great if you can attach a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) instance, that will be easier to solve your issue, Good luck!